# Graphics.DrawString constraints on Font.Size

Tags: c#, graphics

Is there any lower bound on `Font.Size` for the `Graphics.DrawString` method?

This problem arised when i tried to get blocks for all characters of the string, using `Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges` for a small font.

Example code:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        string text = "\\";
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 1.5f);
        RectangleF rectangle1 = new RectangleF(0, 0, 10, 10);
        RectangleF rectangle2 = new RectangleF(0.1f, 0, 10, 10);
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new[] {new CharacterRange(0, 1)});
        Region[] regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rectangle1, stringFormat);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(regions[0].GetBounds());
        regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rectangle2, stringFormat);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(regions[0].GetBounds());
```

Example output:

```
{X=0,Y=0,Width=1,Height=3}
{X=0,Y=0,Width=0,Height=0}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you need such a small font?

Comment: I am trying to draw a set of text blocks, given bounding box and text.

Comment: well I think you are trying to set a font size to fit the size of the box right?

Comment: Actually, it is a little bit more complicated, but the main idea is right. I first calculate font size for a line of text blocks, and then i try to enlarge their bounding boxes. I use `Graphics.MeasureString` to calculate the size of entire text in block, and it works fine. But when i try to get character boxes it fails.

Comment: I want to remove all the blocks with small font size. So i am interested in lower bound for it.

Comment: the reason I ask is that I have worked a lot with Graphics.MeasureString and I think I can help but I don't get what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41246/discussion-between-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani-and-skyterx)